# Not able to display div with style.display='block';

Tags: javascript, jsp

Not able to display div with `style.display='block';`
i have a jsp with style as display : none
i want to set display as block in javascript
i have written below code but its not working
also i have tried to set display in document.ready
strangely it was working but after refreshing page 2 3 times.
result here is loaded by making ajax call.

jsp code:

```
<c:set var="projVar" value="ssc-portal-2.0.3.x"/>
<div style="display: none;" id="<c:out value="${projVar}"/>">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
// result is : ssc-portal-2.0.3.x@/P_ssc@@SSC00004951@/P_ssc(WI-  1409);,
function populateActivityInfo(result) {

    var resultProjArr = result.split(',');
    var tempProjName = '';
    var activityList = '';
    var tempProj = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < resultProjArr.length; i++) {
        if (trim(resultProjArr[i]) != '') {;
            tempProjName = resultProjArr[i].split('@@')[0];
            activityList = resultProjArr[i].split('@@')[1];
            tempProj = trim(tempProjName.split('@')[0]);
            //here tempProj is ssc-portal-2.0.3.x
            document.getElementById(tempProj).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before using `document.getElementById(tempProj).style.display = 'block';` try `alert(tempProj );`

Comment: check your console for any errors

Answer (score 1):

You say the id is `ssc-portal-2-0-3-x`

```
//here tempProj is ssc-portal-2-0-3-x
document.getElementById(tempProj).style.display = 'block';
```

While the id should be `ssc-portal-2.0.3.x`.

```
<c:set var="projVar" value="ssc-portal-2.0.3.x"/>
```

Comment: It's probably a typo. You can see in the jsp that the ID is correctly set to `ssc-portal-2.0.3.x`.

Comment: @Christoph - Typos are the most common mistakes. I'm not going to assume that the values probably are correct while the question states they don't.

Comment: @Ravindra Gullapalli - In the codes comment. It might be a typo. It also could be the other way around. Just pointing out a discrepancy.